# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, to start, I was making a discord bot (using discord.py) and making a help command, but it shows an error when I run the python file

I have no idea what was going on about this... (\n didn't cause the problem)

code (new one):

```
@client.command(aliases=["commands","cmds"], description="Get command list")
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Commands",description="List of the bot's commands",color=0xFF0000)
    for commands in client.commands:
        embed.add_field(name=commands,value=commands.description)
    await ctx.send(embed)
```

and full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Codes\Python\bot.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1262, in decorator
    result = command(*args, **kwargs)(func)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1433, in decorator
    return cls(func, name=name, **attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.description = inspect.cleandoc(kwargs.get('description', ''))
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 632, in cleandoc
    lines = doc.expandtabs().split('\n')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'
```

would be nice if someone could help me

also, this is my first post (and I'm new here) so I don't know much about Stack Overflow

(PS: I have `client.help_command = None` in my code, thanks Kermit)

Comment: You are iterating `commands` but using `command` when getting the value

Comment: Fixed it, I forgot to change the array for the other commands into a string, sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `description` argument takes a string, not a list. So, it should look like this:

```py
@client.command(aliases=["commands","cmds"], description="Get command list")
```

Also, make sure you have `client.help_command = None` somewhere in your code, so that the default `help` command provided by discord.py can be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate issue is that the `description` kwarg of the command decorator is being given a list when it expects a string, which can be found out from the [Command documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#command).

However more importantly, as it appears you're trying to create your own help command, that is not the recommended way to do so since you forgo the advantages of the existing `HelpCommand` framework that handles argument parsing for you. If you need *help* with using it, check out [this guide](https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96) which goes through subclassing and adding it to your bot.

Sidenote: for future questions, please provide the full error message so it's easier for other users to debug.